# Остановить звук уведомления

Tags: android, уведомления

Отправляю уведомление с длинной мелодией, делаю `notificationBuilder.setSound()`,  мелодия играет и замолкает при открытии шторки, все ок, но теперь нужно остановить мелодию программно, оставив уведомление. Как это сделать? Пробовал параллельно с уведомлением запускать мелодию  с помощью `MediaPlayer` и останавливать, но она теперь не замолкает по открытию шторки. Нужно либо выключить мелодию у уведомления, либо подписаться на событие открытия шторки. Есть идеи?

Comment: Тут смотрели? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9622040/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, не останавливается после открытия шторки.